# SQL double table query syntax

Tags: sql, ms-access

In my Access database, I have a table named `ItemPlayerConnection`, that saves an integer named `Item`, another integer named `Player`, and lastly a boolean named `Inventory`. I also have another linked table, named `Item` - in that table, I have a *primary key* named `ItemID`, and a boolean named `ItemIsWeapon`.

What I want to do, is to select all the `Item` integers from the `ItemPlayerConnection` table, where they have their `Player` column on a specific value, which the corroesponding `ItemID` in the `Item` table have their `ItemIsWeapon` on `true`.

What I tried to do is to divide it to two steps : First selecting all the rows where the `item` is set for the correct `player`, and then from there selecting the items which have their `ItemIsWeapon` on `true`.

Here is my query:

```
(SELECT Item
FROM ItemPlayerConnection
WHERE 
    Player='TestPlayer'
    AND
    Inventory=true)
as IDs;
SELECT ItemID 
FROM Item 
WHERE 
    ItemIsWeapon=true
    AND
    ItemID IN IDs
```

I am certain 'TestPlayer' exists -
However, I get an unexplained

> syntax error.

What am I missing?

Comment: i think you are describing a simple JOIN - not even sure what you are intending with this IDs thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably meant to use a `Subquery` like

```
SELECT ItemID 
FROM Item 
WHERE ItemIsWeapon=true
AND ItemID IN (SELECT Item
FROM ItemPlayerConnection
WHERE Player='TestPlayer'
AND Inventory=true)
```

(OR) using a `JOIN` like

```
SELECT i.ItemID 
FROM Item i JOIN ItemPlayerConnection ipc ON i.Item = ipc.ItemID
WHERE i.ItemIsWeapon=true
AND ipc.Player='TestPlayer'
AND ipc.Inventory=true
```

Comment: I meant to use a subquery, and the syntax of what you wrote seems right - Yet I still get a syntax error - one or more of the parameters are missing :/

Comment: Strange! try the other version with `JOIN`

Comment: I figured - the name of the column is ItemIsWepon. I'll edit it - thank you very much!